# create a VCALENDAR parser for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, calendar, eventkit

I am creating an calendar based application in that I want to send all the details to server in the VCALENDAR formate to the server and in the same way need to read it.

I know the event kit programming but using that I am getting a big string and I need to parse It, so how to do that ?

Can any one suggest me how to create/read VCALENDAR for iPhone any sample code or tutorial will be a great help.

thanks in advance

Comment: I want the same parser method as we all perform with the VCARD for Reading and Parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Seem you have to parse it following the standard set by [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)

You get more in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCalendar#vCalendar_1.0)